# Why does my reactjs project on hostinger give a 404 error when opening a new tab or refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, domain-driven-design

I have deployed reactjs project on hostinger where i open any new tab or refresh the page it give error 404

i have used latest version of react router dom

```
Index.js
<Browserrouter>
<App/>
<Browserrouter/>


App.js

<Routes>
<Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path="/about-us" element={<Aboutus/>}/>
        <Route path="/contact-us" element={<Contactus/>}/>
        <Route path="/career" element={<Career/>}/>
        <Route path="/work" element={<Work/>}/> 
        <Route path="/services" element={<ServicesMain/>}/>

<Routes/>
```

Comment: Your index is a bit suspect. Watch the Pascal casing on `BrowserRouter`, and you're not closing that component properly. It should be `</BrowserRouter>`. Does this work locally? Have you tested it?

Comment: I have wrote this mannually...Its written in Pascal casing

Comment: This is because opening a new tab or refreshing does a new request to the server. On the root path `/` then it's fine, but when you go onto any routes beyond that, those paths aren't actually set up on hostinger, which simply hosts your entire built app at a single root route. I believe the options are to either use a hash router, or to have a hosting environment where you control the server (i.e. can implement a server that has a catch all route that just always returns your app, regardless of the route being requested). If you Google "react router 404 refresh" or similar, you can see deeper

Comment: Should be able to fix this with a rewrite in `.htaccess`. You need to redirect `/` to `/index.html`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is not with the React but your hosting config. You need to add rewrite rules by adding `.htaccess` file inside your 'public' folder with the following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```